# How setup alerts notification for override of TFS custom checkin policy?

Tags: tfs

I have a TFS custom checkin policy in place for my TFS 2010. Unfortunately, thee is no provision to disable the override feature for a check in policy. My concern is, how can I setup email alert for my own custom checkin policy? I have multiple checkin policies enabled on my TFS. I need alerts only for one particular policy is overridden.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The tfs power tools has an alert explorer.

One of the alerts is "Check-In to specific folder with policy overriden", which should do what you need.

Comment: I see that. But, my concern is, if I have multiple custom checkin policies set on the folder, I should only get email if a particular custom checkin policy is overridden. Not any one of those. Please let me know if I am not making myself clear.

Comment: Sorry, I had missed that you were only looking for one of several overrides to be notified. Not sure you can do it in the tool. You could have TFS send a SOAP message to a webservice and have the webservice send you a email based on the specific policy override.